# Android first TableRow is not showing

Tags: android, button, tablerow

I have a weird problem. I derived MessageRow from TableRow. I populated a table with one TableRow (Header) and 100 MessageRows. But when I add the table to the HorizontalScroll view **only the Messagerows are showing**.
If I inspect the table in the debugger, all the rows are there, including the Header, with the right children and text.

This is the simplified code:

```js
public class MessageRow extends TableRow {
    public TextView tvData1;
    public TextView tvData2;
    public TextView tvData3;

    public MessageRow(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MessageRow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        tvData1 = new TextView(context);
        tvData2 = new TextView(context);
        tvData3 = new TextView(context);
    }

    public void setData(String data1, String data2, String data3) {
        tvData1.setText(data1);
        tvData2.setText(data2);
        tvData3.setText(data3);

        addView(tvData1);
        addView(tvData2);
        addView(tvData3);
    }
}
```

The activity code:

```js
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewer);

        mTable = new TableLayout(this);

        HorizontalScrollView hview = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hscroll);
        mTable.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        populate(mTable);
        hview.addView(mTable);
    }


    public void setHeader(TableLayout tl) {
        TableRow mHeader = new TableRow(getContext());
        mHeader.addView(getColumnHeader("Data#1"));
        mHeader.addView(getColumnHeader("Data#2"));
        mHeader.addView(getColumnHeader("Data#3"));
        mHeader.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tl.addView(mHeader);
    }

    public void populate(TableLayout tl) {
        setHeader(tl);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            MessageRow mr = new MessageRow(getContext());
            mr.setMessage("xxx"+i,"yyy"+i,"zzz"+i);
            mr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tl.addView(mr);
        }
    }

    private Button getColumnHeader(String name) {
        Button bt = new Button(getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.rightMargin = params.leftMargin = 2;
        bt.setLayoutParams(params);
        bt.setText(name);
        return bt;
    }
```

Now, I tried *bypassing* the **getColumnHeader()** function like this:

```js
    public void setHeader(TableLayout tl) {
        TableRow mHeader = new TableRow(getContext());
        //mHeader.addView(getColumnHeader("Data#1"));
-->         Button bt1 = new Button(getContext());
-->         bt1.setText("Data#1");
-->         mHeader.addView(bt1);
        //mHeader.addView(getColumnHeader("Data#2"));
-->         Button bt2 = getColumnHeader("Data#2");
-->         mHeader.addView(bt2);

        mHeader.addView(getColumnHeader("Data#3"));
        mHeader.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tl.addView(mHeader);
    }
```

and then bt1 (Data#1) is displayed!!! but not Data#2 or Data#3. This hints that somehow the function **getColumnHeader()** is bad. But not acording to the debugger, when I **inspect** bt1 and bt2 they seem good, I cannot detect what is the **difference** between the manually instantiated button bt1 and the returned button bt2.

*Side note: I don't know if this is the best way, but to compare the two variables I just right-clicked and Copy Variable, then pasted it to notepad++ in two different files (one for bt1 and one for bt2) and used the compare plugin.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last piece of the puzzle.
I tried many variations and finally it worked!
Replacing **LayoutParams** with **TableRow.LayoutParams** did the trick.
Their structure is very similar, probably even TableRow.LayoutParams is derived from LayoutParams.
I will leave the mystery here, until some expert sheds light on why this happened.
The final code:

```js
private Button getColumnHeader(String name) {
    Button bt = new Button(getContext());
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.rightMargin = params.leftMargin = 2;
    bt.setLayoutParams(params);
    bt.setText(name);
    return bt;
}
```

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem accept your own answer so the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info.
 I managed to display the buttons, further debug showed that setting the Layout params for each button in the function **getColumnHeader()** caused the problem.
 Still I don't know why.
The button member mLayoutParams being null is OK, but when created (**.setLAyoutParams()**) and assigned values (for example width and height) the suddenly the button is not displayed.
This is the patch,... until I figure out why.

```
private Button getColumnHeader(String name) {
    Button bt = new Button(getContext());
    //LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //params.rightMargin = params.leftMargin = 2;
    //bt.setLayoutParams(params);
    bt.setText(name);
    return bt;
}
```