# Android Making a table look like I want

Tags: android, user-interface, tablelayout, tablerow

I am having a little bit of trouble making the table look like I intend to.
These are a few questions, but since they all refer to the picture below and the details I provide I thought they should all be in a single post.

Here is what I achieved so far:

[image]

The header row contains one element of type Button.

```js
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button bt = new Button(getContext());
    bt.setText("Column1");
    mHeader.addView(bt, params);
    mHeader.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    addView(mHeader);
```

The rest of the table is poulated like this:
(Messagerow extends TableRow and has a TextView member)

```js
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            MessageRow mr = new MessageRow(getContext());
            // stuff to set the TexView text and color
            mr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            this.addView(mr);
        }
```

**1. How can I make the header row height be more like the rows?**

**2. How can I make the button occupy the full width of the row?**

If the table is empty, no text rows just header, then the button matches the row width. As soon as I add a row of text, the column width is adapted but the button width is not.

**3. How can I make the row fill the screen width? (MATCH_PARENT does not do it)**

**4. How can I draw a thin line between the table rows?**

I tried to override the onDraw() function on MessageRow, but it never gets called, not even once.

Don't get me wrong. I am not asking that you do my work for me. These are issues I tried to solve by myself and googled them and read similar posts, but did not find an answer.
*Note: I find that UI design in Javascript for Android lacks clear control and clear documentation over all these little details.*

**Edit**
This is how I create the table:

```js
    TableLayout mTable = new TableLayout(this);

    HorizontalScrollView hview = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hscroll);

    populate(mTable);
    mTable.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams( TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mTable.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    hview.addView(mTable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How can I make the header row height be more like the rows?

Using the default `Button` there isn't much to do. The `Button` uses a nine-patch image that has some space between the button's text and the borders that you see. You could use a smaller font but that you'll probably look ugly. Another thing to try is using your own background for the Button and get rid of the default extra space(of the default nine-patch image) so the final height is near the height of the text from the `TextView`s. Or  try to enforce a standard height for all rows using a fixed value.

> 1. How can I make the button occupy the full width of the row?

I think that you have more then one `TextView` in `MessageRow` so when you add the `Button` it moves to the first column(corresponding to the first `TextView`). If this is the case, make your `Button` *span* across the number of columns representing the number of `TextViews` in `MessageRow`:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.span = 3; // if you have 3 `TextView` in the MessageRow
    Button bt = new Button(getContext());
    bt.setText("Column1");
    mHeader.addView(bt, params);
```

If this is not the case add more details.

> 1. How can I make the row fill the screen width? (MATCH_PARENT does not do it)

As I said on one of your previous questions, I don't know why that happens(but I gave you some solutions there to overcome this issue). Also:

1. `mHeader` and the other `MessageRow` are children of a `Tablelayout` and the correct `LayoutParams` to use on them is the `LayoutParams` of the parent: `TableLayout.LayoutParams` and **not** `TableRow.LayoutParams`.
2. You add some `TextView` in the `MessageRow`(from what I seen in your previous questions), add those child views with `TableRow.LayoutParams` to `MessageRow`.
3. You use only `WRAP_CONTENT` for your `LayoutParams` everywhere in your code, you might want to set the width(the first parameter in the constructor) to `FILL_PARENT`/`MATCH_PARENT`

> 1. How can I draw a thin line between the table rows?

You could use a simple `View` that will act as a separator:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   MessageRow mr = new MessageRow(getContext());
   // stuff to set the TexView text and color
   mr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   this.addView(mr);
   View separator = new View(getContext());
   separator.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 3)));
   separator.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   this.addView(separator);
}
```

Because you have 100 rows you could try to set a drawable with a separator line as the background for the`TableRow`(`header` and `MessageRow`) instead of the above method that adds another 100 Views to the layout.

**Extra Note:**

You have a lot of views to add to a single activity layout, you are talking about 100 rows, and if your `MessageRow` is more complex than a simple `TextView`(and I think it is) you could get in some performances problems. I suggest you take a look at the wonderful `ListView` widget.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it gives good leads. I will try the background drawable with separator for the Row (will it strech to the row width?). Regarding WRAP_CONTENT/MATCH_PARENT I tried all the combinations on the button and the tablerow without success. LayoutParams causes the Header row to not be displayed (see my [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259562/android-first-tablerow-is-not-showing). The span thing will not work for me; there are other TextViews, visibility GONE. And besides, when they are visible I will have one button header for each.

Comment: @ilomambo The drawable will fill the width of the view. I suggest you to try to replace your `TableLayout` with a `ListView`.

Comment: @ilomambo Because you'll avoid the issues with rows filling/not filling the entire width, it will have a performance boost over your current over 100 views/layout. `ListView` already has a separator between rows and you could pretty easy make it look like a `table`. Of course the `ListView` comes with its own issues but I think that overall  the `ListView` is much better. Anyway it was just a suggestion.

Comment: I tried the drawable as background to draw the row separator and it works great. Just don't know how it will scale to Tablets. The Button size is also solved, while researching your advice I found there is a 9patch tool included in the android SDK. I defined a new 9-patch for the button with no margins at all... and voila! the button became smaller.

Comment: Regarding the ListView, if I understand correctly I would have to generate each line to look like a table. In my case I think it is not an option, because in the end I want to be able to "hide" columns, which can be simply done in a Table by setting the visibility to GONE. With the ListView approach I would have to regenerate the lines each time I want to hide/show a column.

Comment: @ilomambo The drawable will work no matter, phone/tablet(I hope that you DIDN'T use a fixed size image(a nine-patch image or a xml drawable is the way to go here)). Regarding the `ListView` my concern was related to the overall performance of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a programming environment here, but I'll try and answer some of your questions.

1. The reason your header row (button) is taller than your test based rows is because the button requires more space and the row accomodates it. The default button has padding on both the top/bottom of the text. I think your best option is to create your own button, which gives you the additional benefit of being able to control the look and feel. It seems like other people have had this issue before: [Can't get rid of bottom padding on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211774/cant-get-rid-of-bottom-padding-on-button)
2. Your button is set to wrap_content which means it won't be any bigger than it needs to be (It will grow/shrink so it can fit the text "Column1" or whatever you put there). Instead of making the Button WRAP, I suspect you'll need to make it FILL_PARENT.
3. It's not your Table Row that needs to fill the screen width, it's your table that needs to fill the screen. Wherever you define your table, it's *probably* set to WRAP_CONTENT for the Horizontal dimension. Set it to FILL_PARENT and your table should expand to the full width of whatever it's container is (In this case, it should expand the full width of the screen)
4. There are probably several different ways you can do this. One method I used somewhat recently is to utilize the View tag which essentially looks like a horizontal bar across the screen. Below is a link to how to implement it.
   http://sonnygill.net/android/horizontal-rule/

Comment: 1. Will try it. *** 2.I tried already MATCH_PARENT on the button, with the same result. *** 3.My table has MATCH_PARENT on the width, I even set the background color to white to see exactly where it ends. *** $.I came across your link before, I am just concerned about the memory usage if I put so many views (In my final app I expect to manage several thousands rows)

Comment: @ilomambo It can be tough to figure out layouts in code-behind. I'd suggest creating this in an XML layout and playing with that until you find the layout you want, then transcribing it into the code-behind logic. I find it much much easier to play around with the XML layout editor.

Can you post the code where you create the table? 

An alternative to creating VIEW's for horizontal lines is to create a 9-patch image to use as your textview background. Create an image that has a horizontal line at the bottom and use that as the "background" for your text and set to FILL_PARENT.

Comment: I added the table creation code to the question. XML won't help me here, I don't know how to do any of those things either in XML. I discarded the VIEW  as horizontal separator, see my answer to Luksprog.